# unknown component in datasheet

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor, converter

im using xl6009 dc to dc  converter , in page no 7 of datasheet the sepic inverting topology is show which generates  12 and -12v .my doubt is what component is used, is it a transformer or coupled inductor my hunch is it is a coupled inductor but those have only four terminals please help

link for datasheet

https://e-radionica.com/productdata/XL6009.pdf

Comment: Something like this? http://www.soanar.com/store/category/369/product/mm2014.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This might be clearer if we redraw the circuit so the topology is clear:

[image: Basic SEPIC with coupled inductors]

This is the same topology as in the datasheet, but it is clearer how it operates, and it is clearly a coupled inductor.

There is an excellent description of how this topology operates in this [application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt309/slyt309.pdf).

You can search for the part you need at the excellent [Coilcraft](http://www.coilcraft.com/apps/coupled_finder/coupled_finder.cfm) coupled inductor finder.

Comment: this  sepic generates only postive .you must the sepic inverter in page 7 which generates both postive and negative

Answer (score 0):

A coupled inductor is like a tranformer, they can be built with any number of windings.

However. in the diagram on page it can be seen that the current flows in the primaries and secondary at the same time.  this makes it a type of forwards converter, which calls for a transformer, not a coupled inductor.

edit:  some sort of ferrite cored transformer

Comment: whats a transformer doing in dc application

Comment: Well the DC is oscillating so transformers will work as long as it is oscillating.